ggplot2 density2d vs seaborn kde / Or shorter range in density2d
2D density plot seems to exclude some areas, I assume, because of too small number of points comparing to the 'main cloud'. Interestingly, it seems to work better in seaborn kde plot.
Below you can find figures for comparison and the code. The file "density2d_test_df.csv" can be downloaded here. Note the bottom-right part of the density plot. In seaborn it's better visible that there is some part of data. Furthermore, by coloring with respect to a third variable, I can see which group is contributing more to that region. And this is practically impossible in the ggplot plots.
What is the reason of such behaviour? Is there a way to make my ggplot plot to be similar to seaborn?
I have tried to play around with parameters such as n, h, and bins but that does not help.
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("density2d_test_df.csv")

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.3) +
    geom_density2d()

# Same plot split by third variable
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.3) +
    geom_density2d(aes(color=group))



import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("density2d_test_df.csv")

sns.displot(df, x="x", y="y", kind="kde", fill=False)
sns.displot(df, x="x", y="y", hue="group", kind="kde", fill=False)




Your question as written is very vague. Adjusting the bandwith and the number of bins should help, but we cannot check since we don't have your example data. You can explore using kernel density estimators like show here.

I uploaded the example data. Now I believe it should be reproducible. I've played around with all parameters I found for geom_density2d. Maybe I missed some specific combination, but I would like to understand it rather than guessing. That's one of the reasons I decided to ask.
